# how to define interface for the following date type

Tags: angular, typescript, ecmascript-6, interface, angular9

I am trying to define interface type for this.usedPercentageFilterOptions . Do you know if the following declaration of interface is correct?

`

```
  interface Item {
     filterPillValue: string,
     id: string,
    label: string
}
interface Items {
    radio: Item,
    checkbox: Item
}
   public usedPercentageFilterOptions: Items[]

   this.usedPercentageFilterOptions = [
        {
          radio:  { filterPillValue: 'used%', id:'filter-used-%', label: 'Used %' },
          checkbox: [
            { filterPillValue: 'Full', id:'filter-full', label: 'Full' },
            { filterPillValue: 'Reached Critical threshold', id:'filter-critical-threshold', label: 'Reached Critical threshold' },
            { filterPillValue: 'Reached Warning threshold', id:'filter-warning-threshold', label: 'Reached Warning threshold' },
            { filterPillValue: 'Not reached threshold', id:'filter-not-reached-threshold', label: 'Not reached threshold' }
          ]
        }
    ];`
```

Comment: Yeah its correct the only issue I found you made checkbox single object but its array all you need to add `checkbox: Item[]`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
 export interface Cb {
       filterPillValue?: string;
       id?: string;
       label?: string
    }
```

And

```
export interface UsedPer {
       radio?: Cb;
       checkbox?: Cb[]
   }
```

Hope useful